# C# parsing issue with '+' characters

Tags: c#, string, parsing, encoding, iso-8859-1

I need your help with this issue:
My colleague made a program (asp.net) that allows you to write a sentence on a textbox, and then put it in a Word document.
this code runs a specific instruction:

```
string item = "";
item = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(item, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

in this 'ITEM' you can write anything; however if you put a '+' series, it shows only the first.

```
"+ hello world +€"  -->  "+ hello world €".
```

can someone tell me why if I write so many '+' characters, only the first one is displayed?

Thanks

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("+ hello world +€", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))` returns `"  hello world  €"` as `+` is interpreted as an escaped space (like %20) so the issue is likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the UrlDecode method interpreting the + as a space. Try using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string item = "+ hello world +€";
item = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item);
```